# Access Violation on Const Atomic Variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, visual-c++

When executing the following c++ code in Visual Studio 2012 it generates the following error: Access violation writing location 0xADDRESS. This "application" will compile and execute without issue if the variable "alwaysFalse" is non-const. What I don't understand is why when it's const it causes a **runtime** access violation? This is not an issue with the constructor, as it compiles just fine with and without const. Only when it is const does the error occur; using a non-const the application code will work exactly as expected.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

namespace
{

const std::atomic_bool alwaysFalse = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(false);

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (alwaysFalse)
        std::cout << "It's true" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "It's false" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of using `const` atomic  variable? Why not to use just `const` variable?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. VS2012 is ancient - upgrade your compiler.

Comment: Appears to be a known bug.